# Is it possible to run a windows guest in a linux host on KVM in google cloud nested virtualization?

Tags: kvm, google-cloud-platform

Is it possible to run a windows guest in a linux host on KVM in google cloud nested virtualization?

We know Google now provides for nested virtualization, in theory they say you can run a linux guest on a linux host using kvm hypervisor as explained in the link below. Does this allow for windows guest?

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-nested-virtualization-vm-instances

Answer (score 1):

In nested virtualization it doesn't matter what virtual machines you run (as level 2) in the nested hypervisor. Google is saying that you can only run Linux and KVM as the nested hypervisor (level 1) and that they do not support ESXi, Xen or Windows at level 1. You can run anything you want at level 2, even operating systems not otherwise possible to run in Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Windows 10 at L2 is working. But if you are using libvirt, you have to enable HPET / high precision event timer (libvirt adds `-no-hpet`, and with this flag, you have boot problems). You can solve this issue by editing the xml file and change `<timer name='hypervclock' present='no'/>` to `<timer name='hypervclock' present='yes'/>`.
For windows Versions below 10, this is not requied.

Answer (score -1):

At this point, the doc says:

```
Nested virtualization does not currently support Windows instances.
```